# "be getting to do"

Tags: get-be

Is "I'm getting to forget about him" correct? Or does it mean that someone tries not to forget but he/she does it like when the time pass? I'm really curious, so please help.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. The meaning of a phrase is hard to know without its context. As it stands, "getting" could mean "allowed" or any number of other things. When you want help understanding someone else's expression, please provide plenty of context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote sounds wrong. It is very difficult, if not impossible, to construe a contextual scenario in which your sentence could possibly make any sense. Here, however, is one such:

> Just what are you getting out of this cross-country road trip?
>
> I'm getting to forget about him; that's the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound correct, although I can think of a few phrases that support this grammatical structure:

- "I'm getting to know him."
- "I'm getting to help out around the house more."

Even so, most phrases with "get+to" are typically followed by a noun.

I would reword the phrase if I were you.

Comment: Yes - it's a substitute for 'beginning to', but with a hint of accomplishment involved. Unusually, we wouldn't say 'I'm beginning to know him', but the 'begin to + verb' catenation is used in a far larger number of constructions. Certainly, we wouldn't usually say 'I'm getting to forget about him' - and 'I'm starting to forget about him' doesn't sound as sensible as 'I'd almost forgotten about him'.